# Using AuditInterceptor - object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, instance, transient

The domain model the DomainObject's **audit fields** are populated using an **AuditInterceptor**.

> ```
> DomainObject
>    Id
>    EstablishDate
>    EstablishId
>    UpdateDate
>    UpdateId
>
> Message : DomainObject
>    Description
>    MessageDistributions
>
> Distribution : DomainObject
>    BeginEffective
>    EndEffective
>    MessageDistributions
>
> MessageDistribution : DomainObject
>    Distribution
>    Message
> ```

In this *ManyToMany* relationship the **MessageDistribution** also implements the **DomainObject** in order to use the AuditInterceptor. This keeps me from using the **HasManyToMany** clause in the FluentNHibernate Mapping.

Here is the mapping code.

```
public class MessageMap : ClassMap<Message>
{
  public MessageMap()
    {
        WithTable("Message");

        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().ColumnName("MessageSeq").WithUnsavedValue(0);
        Map( x => x.Description ).ColumnName( "SummaryName" );
        Map(x => x.EstablishDate);
        Map(x => x.EstablishId);
        Map(x => x.UpdateDate);
        Map(x => x.UpdateId);


        HasMany( x => x.MessageDistributions )
            .KeyColumnNames.Add( "MessageSeq" )
            .Access.AsCamelCaseField( Prefix.Underscore )
            .Cascade.All().Inverse();

    }
}

public class MessageDistributionMap : ClassMap<MessageDistribution>
{
    public MessageDistributionMap()
    {
        WithTable("MessageDistribution");

        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().ColumnName("MessageDistributionSeq").WithUnsavedValue(0);

        Map(x => x.EstablishDate);
        Map(x => x.EstablishId);
        Map(x => x.UpdateDate);
        Map(x => x.UpdateId);

        References(x => x.Message).ColumnName("MessageSeq");
        References(x => x.Distribution).ColumnName("DistributionSeq");
    }
}

public class DistributionMap : ClassMap<Distribution>
{
    public DistributionMap()
    {
        WithTable("Distribution");

        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().ColumnName("DistributionSeq").WithUnsavedValue(0);

        Map(x => x.BeginEffectiveDate);
        Map(x => x.EndEffectiveDate);
        Map(x => x.EstablishDate);
        Map(x => x.EstablishId);
        Map(x => x.UpdateDate);
        Map(x => x.UpdateId);

        HasMany( x => x.MessageDistributions )
            .KeyColumnNames.Add( "DistributionSeq" )
            .Access
            .AsCamelCaseField( Prefix.Underscore )
            .Cascade.All().Inverse();
    }
}
```

Below is a test to implement the above relationship.

```
[Test]
public void Should_Add_A_Message_To_Existing_Distribution()
{
    var desc = "Test message " + DateTime.Now;
    var message = new Message { Description = desc, PumpType = 1 };

    var distribution = new Distribution
                           {
                               BeginEffectiveDate = new DateTime( 2009, 9, 2 ),
                               EndEffectiveDate = new DateTime( 2009, 9, 10 ),
                               Priority = 1
                           };
    var messageDistribution = new MessageDistribution { Distribution = distribution };

    message.AddMessageDistribution(messageDistribution);

    _repository.Save( message );
    _repository.Clear();

    var retrievedMessage = _repository.GetById(message.Id);

    Assert.AreEqual(message, retrievedMessage);

    Assert.AreEqual(distribution, retrievedMessage.MessageDistributions[0].Distribution);
}
```

I execute the test using a test runner and it results in the following error on the line _repository.Save( message );

> ```
>     NHibernate.TransientObjectException: 
>     object references an unsaved transient instance - 
> save the transient instance before flushing: 
>     Speedway.StoreOperations.CrindMessaging.Core.Domain.Distribution
> ```

In my AuditInterceptor I have a

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", propertyNames[i], state[i]));
```

in the "OnSave and OnFlushDirty" events.

I can see the Message and MessageDistribution are coming through but the Distribution entity never gets touched.

So my question is, is there something wrong with my FluentMapping? Do I have the "Inverse" in the wrong place? Has anyone run across this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your FluentMapping looks OK.
Try to change the following line in your test:

```
var messageDistribution = new MessageDistribution { Distribution = distribution };
```

with this:

```
var messageDistribution = new MessageDistribution { Distribution = distribution, Message = message };
```

and try again.